# How do I force Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER) to use my sentence delimitations?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Is there an option in Stanford NER toolkit to force the output to have the same line splits as the input?

I'm looking for something similar to "-sentences newline" option in Stanford parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the option `-tokenizerOptions "tokenizeNLs=true,tokenizePerLine=true"` then each line will be treated as a separate sentence, which should give the results you are hoping for - it will be written as one line if you use an outputFormat like `slashTags` or `inlineXML`.

CoreNLP also provides some options for processing text line by line.